# Why priority queue re-order element when I do poll()?

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

Today when I poll() element from priority queue, I realized after poll() element, the rest of element in queue change the order. basically I have priority queue and I override Comparator method to let them order by how many time it show up in string (max heap)

```
Queue<Character> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Character>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Character a, Character b) {
        if(map.get(a) == map.get(b)) {
            return map.get(a) - map.get(b);
        }
        return map.get(b) - map.get(a);
    }
});
```

if I have a string "aabbcc", the frequency of each character will be

```
['a':2, 'b':2, 'c':2]
```

and priority queue will be

```
['a','b','c']
```

when I did poll(), the priority queue become to:

```
['c', 'b']
```

why not ['b','c']?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PriorityQueues store their elements in a heap (a min heap by default, but this can be changed with `Collections.reverseOrder()` passed to the constructor). This data structure only guarantees that the first element, or the element received from `poll()` will be the smallest element in the queue based on the natural ordering of the elements. When an object is removed, the queue is "heapified" to maintain the guarantee that the minimum element will be the next one polled. When you print the queue by calling the toString method, the heap is getting printed in a level order traversal, which is not necessarily representative of how the elements are being stored.

You can read more about heaps [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), and about tree traversals [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)